# How can I replace the first occurence of a sub-string in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I have a string `this is a simple example. this is another simple example.` and a dict of sub-strings and the sub-strings the first occurence of the sub-string shall be replaced with

```
substitutions = {
    "a": "no",
    "simple": "difficult",
}
```

The resulting string shall be `this is no difficult example. this is another simple example.`. How can I implement this?

Comment: Replacing only once is an option [according to the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.replace` with `count` param

**Ex:**

```
substitutions = {
    "a": "no",
    "simple": "difficult",
}

s = "this is a simple example. this is another simple example."

for k, v in substitutions.items():
    s = s.replace(k, v, 1)
print(s)
```

Comment: Be careful though, this solution replaces strings one after another, not all at once.

Comment: @Rakesh Uh, I missed `count`. Thx